# How to bind string properties from object in repeat.for

Tags: visual-studio-code, html-table, binding, aurelia, aurelia2

I have a list of arrays in a table displayed using repeat.for. I need to display tr row in blue color when "receiving.supplier === `Scrap Separated`" and blue color row when the result is "receiving.supplier === `Scrap Sorted`". Is there any way I can do it with if.bind but for String that I got in network tab. Here is my network and code.[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not use images for text information.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is purely a CSS question. You can have CSS rules based on `[data-supplier]` and assign a different background color based on the value of the `supplier` property.

The example CSS rules can be as follows.

```css
tr[data-supplier="Scrap Separated"] {
    background-color: blue;
}

tr[data-supplier="Scrap Sorted"] {
    background-color: green;
}
```

And then bind the `data-supplier` property in the markup.

```html
<tr data-supplier="${recieving.supplier}">
...
</tr>
```

Note that you cannot possibly nest `div` directly under `tbody` as that will be evicted by browser being non-conformed element as per the expected schema.